# asp.net AjaxFileUpload not working

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I have implemented bootstrap design in my asp.net application with ajaxcontrol toolkit v17.0.
I need to implement AjaxFileUpload, but it not showing properly on my page and even when I click on it, it not responding anything, file selection popup not open, and even no browser console error is there.
[image]

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="fuSpecialReportFiles" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="png, jpg, jpeg, bmp" OnUploadComplete="fuSpecialReportFile_UploadComplete" />
```

Comment: I assume you are using IE and document mode is set to IE 7 (F12 ->Emulation-Document mode). Try to force it to the edge using meta attribute `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do`

Comment: No it's in chrome